# Function declared within mock is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I have the following code in Jest:

```
  const mockOnNextAction = jest.fn(() => {
       then: jest.fn();
   });
   jest.mock('NativeModules', () => {
       return {
           MyNativeModule: {
               onNextAction: mockOnNextAction
           }
       };
   });

 MyNativeModule.executeSomeChecks();
 expect(NativeModules.MyNativeModule.onNextAction).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(NativeModules.MyNativeModule.onNextAction().then).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

In the code I am testing, I would like to make a call like this one:

```
NativeModules.MyNativeModule.onNextAction().then(() => {
    //contents of callback function
});
```

The problem is that in the code under test I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Also, the following print statement:

```
 console.log("NativeModules.MyNativeModule.onNextAction: " + JSON.stringify(NativeModules.MyNativeModule.onNextAction));
```

has the result `undefined`

So why is `onNextAction` undefined? I am mocking it with Jest so it should exist.

Comment: if you wish to return object in an arrow function, wrap object in parenthesis.

Comment: If I do that, `onNextAction` will be called but `then` will not be called. So only the first `expect` will be satisfied, not the second.

Comment: This: `) => {
       then: jest.fn();
   }` is incorrect syntax. It shold be either `() => ({...})` or `() => { return {...} }`

Comment: You are right. I modified it to `() => ({...})`, but it is still not called. Same for `() => { return {...} }`.

Comment: Few more issues `then: jest.fn()` will call the function immediately. Yo will have to pass reference, I guess. Try `then: jest.fn` and then in expect, try `...then(); expect(jest.fn).toHaveBeenCalled()`. Note, I have never used jest. This is more of a conceptual suggestion. Another issue is, you have have semicolon in object. Thats illegal.

Comment: In the end, I found out the final problem. I should have factored out the declaration of `then` into a different variable because I was getting a new instance in the `expect` which of course was not called. Thank you for guiding me to the solution!

Comment: Glad I was able to help! If you think this issue can be faced my others, add a detailed answer about debugging and resolution. If not, feel free to remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems with my mock.

1.I was not respecting ES6 lambda function syntax, so I changed to: `() => ({...})` and I removed the `;` inside the object.

2.I made the `then` field reference the same variable, otherwise `NativeModules.MyNativeModule.onNextAction().then` would always be a new object which was not called.

Finally, my code looks like this:

```
const mockThen = jest.fn();
const mockOnNextAction = jest.fn(() => ({
     then: mockThen
 }));
 jest.mock('NativeModules', () => ({
     MyNativeModule: {
         onNextAction: mockOnNextAction
     }
 }));
```